# Is it possible to write to Database via jaydebeapi package (python)?

Tags: python, database, jdbc, teradata, jaydebeapi

With the jaydebeapi package in python it is possible to read from Teradata tables (or probably from every other DB). However i did not find any documentation about writing to the database via jdbc? (The best documentation I found was this --> [Link](https://www.mapd.com/docs/latest/mapd-core-guide/jaydebeapi/))

Is this not possible?

Or is it just possible with another package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [the REAMDE](https://github.com/baztian/jaydebeapi/blob/master/README.rst) JayDeBeApi implements [Python DB-API v2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/). Basically you have to call the `execute` on a cursor and pass the insert statement.

But you are right. Some more guidance for novices would be nice. Mybe the [Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DatabaseProgramming/) or the [docs for the sqlite implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) give you some guidance.

Adapting one rather basic sqlite example:

```
import jaydebeapi
conn = jaydebeapi.connect(...)
curs = conn.cursor()     
curs.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)") ##changes c to curs
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: What goes inside the call to jaydebeapi.connect()? An example would be very helpful